# Fallback for authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, authorization

I'm working on a piece of automation that generates a list of allowed public keys and overwrites a server's user `~./ssh/authorized_keys`. Is there a way to prevent a mistake in the automation to completely block me from accessing the host? I have some limitations, the server itself is from a VM image that gets updates over time, so creating additional users is not something I would like to pursue.

So far I've thought of:

- Would it be possible to have composition of `authorized_keys`. If there were 2 files, I could have a dynamic file and one of the files with a static fallback key.
- I will still do a testing before the overwrite (like checking for contents and format of keys) to ensure I'm not copying an empty file. But still, something could go wrong.

Is composition a possibility? If not do you folks have other ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sshd` by default already checks `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`.  This is configurable with the `AuthorizedKeysFile` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which can take a list of multiple files to check.  From `sshd_config(5)`:

> AuthorizedKeysFile
>
> Specifies the file that contains the public keys used for user
> authentication.  The format is described in the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE
> FORMAT section of sshd(8).  Arguments to AuthorizedKeysFile accept the
> tokens described in the TOKENS section.  After expansion,
> AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path or one relative to
> the user's home directory. Multiple files may be listed, separated by
> whitespace.  Alternately this option may be set to none to skip
> checking for user keys in files.  The default is ".ssh/authorized_keys
> .ssh/authorized_keys2".

Comment: thank you @satwell!